# How to execute PowerShell script while creating a Custom Project Template in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, project-template

I am creating a Custom Visual Studio Project Template. This custom project template consists of two folders which needs to contain some binaries. These binaries has to copied from some server location. As these binaries will be updated periodically i can't simply enclose them while creating the custom project template. I would like to copy them from server location whenever the developer selects this custom project template the two folders inside their Visual Studio might get the latest binaries from the server location. I have to do this with PowerShell script only. Can someone help me on how to execute PowerShell scripts while creating custom project template in Visual Studio.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain why so ?

Comment: Do you already have a solution for how to "execute PowerShell script" in the project template?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own custom `nuget` packages? Then you only have to "refresh nuget packages" after creating the project from template.